# How to filter the XMPP presence that is received in iOS?

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework, user-presence

I am successfully able to receive presence i.e. status of users in my iOS XMPP client. But within that status is some extra info that I wish to extract. This info was added as a child to the presence while sending.

Here is how I extended presence while sending:

```
- (void)updatePresence:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    XMPPPresence *presence = [XMPPPresence presence];
    NSString *string = [notification object]; // object contains some random string.
    NSXMLElement *status = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"status" stringValue:string];
    [presence addChild:status];
    NSLog(@"presence info :- %@",presence);
    [[self xmppStream] sendElement:presence];
}
```

Now  when I am receiving presence I want to retrieve this extended portion of the presence. How can it be done?

This is how I receive the presence:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
    NSString *presenceType = [presence type]; // online / offline
    NSString *myUsername = [[sender myJID] user];
    NSString *presenceFromUser = [[presence from] user];
    NSString *presenceString=[presence fromStr];
    NSString *string = @"@company.com";

    if ([presenceString rangeOfString:string].location == NSNotFound)
    {
        if (![presenceFromUser isEqualToString:myUsername])
        {
            if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"available"])
            {
                NSMutableDictionary *buddy=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                [buddy setObject:presenceFromUser forKey:@"name"];
                [buddy setObject:[presence fromStr] forKey:@"jid"];

                [_chatDelegate newBuddyOnline:buddy];
            }
            else if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"unavailable"])
            {
                NSMutableDictionary *buddy=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                [buddy setObject:presenceFromUser forKey:@"name"];
                [buddy setObject:[presence fromStr] forKey:@"jid"];
                [_chatDelegate buddyWentOffline:buddy];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give the output you got it with NSLOg

Comment: presence info :- <presence><status>mngmbhj</status></presence>

Comment: So what extended portion you want to receive?

Comment: @Sushrut check my answer may It help you.

Answer (score 4):

Presence Packet look like this

```
    //    <presence xmlns="jabber:client" 
    //    id="Jothb-6" 
    //    from="sender@domain.com/resource" 
    //    to="receiver@domain.com">
    //    <status>Online</status>
    //    <show>presence message</show>
    //    <priority>1</priority>
    //    </presence>
```

To get this:

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
{
        NSXMLElement *showStatus = [presence elementForName:@"status"];
        NSString *presenceString = [showStatus stringValue];
        NSString *customMessage = [[presence elementForName:@"show"]stringValue];

        NSLog(@"Presence : %@, and presenceMessage: %@",presenceString,customMessage);
}
```

Comment: @bhumeshwar- Are you able to send image and video through XMPP